# How to update nuget packages in ASP.NET "Websites" using CLI

Tags: asp.net, nuget, command-line-interface

ASP.NET Websites is legacy application type - it doesn't have a solution or project file.

That being said, can I use Nuget's CLI to update an ASP.NET Website? I'm guessing that it's not possible since Nuget's CLI requires a solution/project file but I'm hoping that I'm wrong. Please prove me wrong people.

Thanks

Comment: So what do you want to update? Does the site already contain a packages.config?

Comment: I want to update an internal nuget package. And, yes, the site already contains a packages.config.